# Dynamically add textbox on the clicked coordinates of the image

Tags: javascript, angular

I am having an image and want to add the textbox on the top of an image whenever a user clicks on the image (coordinates(x,y)).

Comment: Where do you want to add textbox after clicking on image ? at above image or exactly where you clicked on image at that x,y position you want to add textbox ?

Comment: exactly where the user clicked on the image at that x,y position

Comment: And do you want to hide previous textbox  when new click on image occur. ?

Comment: No. I want to keep adding the textboxes whenever a user clicks on image

Comment: Did you implemented any ways or not ? Or you wanted to do it from fresh ?

Comment: Want to start from fresh.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qah2jc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts here is your working demo

Comment: Is above working example demo is what you want ? @Knot

Comment: What are these hard-coded 170 and 25 numbers?

Comment: That's used to detect right and end side of  click. So that you can see full text box. @Knot

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. how you came up with these numbers?

Comment: You can replace this numbers by text-box height and width, so this would be your dynamic way of doing this.

Comment: Ok. I see one issue though. The coordinates do not match the clicked coordinates when we move the image i.e. if we add big text on the top of the image

Comment: thats happens because, textbox has their own style so thats okay.

Answer (score 0):

```js
textboxList = [];

onImageClick(event) {
    console.log(event.offsetX);
    console.log(event.offsetY);

    this.textboxList.push(event);
}
```

```html
<div class="image-wrapper">
    <img (click)="onImageClick($event)" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1621173865296-baaf7dc3afcc">
    
    <div *ngFor="let textbox of textboxList;">
        <input type="text">
    </div>
</div>
```

This will give you the coordinates of the click inside the image. Then, using absolute positioning, position the text box according to these coordinates.

Comment: How to add/create textboxes dynamically inside onImageClick? I know we can use document.createElement but want to know if we have any better way to create it in angular rather than directly using the document

Comment: I have updated the example code. The easiest way is to hide the text field with *ngIf.

Comment: This will add/show only one textbox. I need to keep adding/showing textboxes whenever the user clicks on the particular coordinates.

Comment: Ok, in this case try *ngFor to generate elements in the template. I've updated the example above.